# Replace function gives object doesn't support property or method

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA script has been working just fine until today when this line
    repStr = Replace(currentSID, "t#", "SID_")

The Replace function shows 
All parameters are Strings.  currentSID = "t#3520"

```
Sub AddSID(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim currentSID As String
    Dim maxRow As Long
    Dim repStr As String

    maxRow = sh.Cells(2000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = maxRow To 2 Step -1
        currentSID = sh.Cells(r, 1).Value
        repStr = Replace(currentSID, "t#", "SID_")
        sh.Cells(r, 1).Value = repStr
        currentSID = sh.Cells(r, 1).Value
```

Comment: What's the  value of `maxRow`/`currentSID` when the error occurs?

Comment: Did you rename something (such as a worksheet code module)  to `Replace` ?

Comment: is `sh` really a sheet with a first colum containing "t#" strings ?